# Running mono-based application on Centos Start

Tags: centos, centos6, service, startup, mono

I am very new to Linux and I am currently switching my server from Windows to Centos 6.3.
I have written a small UDP server. UDP server was written in C# and now I adopted it to work with Linux using Mono. It is working fine, when I run it this way:

`/opt/mono/bin/mono /root/MySoft/UDPServer.exe "$@"`

How do I run it automatically--when computer stats? (in windows terms: windows-service)

I tried creating a launcher file and putting it to `/etc/init.d` but it did not work

Comment: What does your init script look like, then? And what does "did not work" mean?

Comment: I created new file with extention .sh and added text: `/opt/mono/bin/mono /root/MySoft/UDPServer.exe "$@"`

Comment: Does not work means that application does not start; when I send test packets to this app, it is not up and running. When I actually go via Interface to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications, and add my application there, it works. But it only start working when user is logged in. But I need my program to run when OS starts.

Answer (score 2):

My goto solution for things like this is to install and use supervisord.

Supervisord is a python process supervisor that is very simple to install from your distro's package repo, and simple to configure. You just add a simple config file for your executable and supervisor takes care of starting it up, capturing output, and (optionally) re-starting it  if the process fails.

An example config would look like this:

```
[program:udp_server]
user = <username>
command = /opt/mono/bin/mono /root/MySoft/UDPServer.exe "$@"
stdout_logfile = /var/log/udp_server-stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stdout_logfile_backups = 5
stderr_logfile = /var/log/udp_server-stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile_backups = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, this solution worked:

I added my line of text `/opt/mono/bin/mono /root/MySoft/UDPServer.exe "$@" &` to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`